# genymotion player.exe has stopped working error

Tags: android, genymotion

For my `Genymotion`, When I click on a new emulator, I am getting below error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

actual problem are in your `graphic card`.please properly update graphic card with your manufacture website or update via windows system.

Last . checked "virtual device path" if path are not set than show this problem & Clean cache in `genymotion`.

Hope problem are solved